# Parametric Sql Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to parametrically sort the SQL statement. SQL statement:
Declare @sxPaletNo varchar(10)
set @sxPaletNo = 'pd.PaletNo'

```
select
    pd.PaletNo PalletNo
    ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletDetay pd
    left join paletsevk ps on pd.PaletNo=ps.SevkPaletNo  
    left Join Cins      cs on pd.mTomrukCinsiKod=cs.EskiKod
where
    pd.YeniPaletNo is Null
    and
    ps.SevkPaletNo is null 
Group By
    pd.PaletNo 
    ,cs.KaplamaIng
Order By @sxPaletNo
```

I am getting the following error:
Msg 1008, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.

What is Suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Database name ?

Comment: Guessing SQL Server from error message format

Comment: my database is DFSEMUS

Comment: Rakesh wasn't really asking about database name but database system you are using: Sql Server, Oracle, MySQL... or any other

Comment: You can't have a column or database as a variable in a sql statement. You will have to use dynamic sql in a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: NO, you can't do that unless making it a dynamic query

Comment: so sorry my system is MSSQL

Comment: can I have a example code @JNevill

Comment: Can I do dynamic query? Can I take an example? @Rahul

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way in SQL as parameters are not designed to replace columns names.

You can:

**Dynamic SQL** assuming @sxPaletNo will always have valid value:

```
DECLARE @sxPaletNo varchar(10);
SET @sxPaletNo = 'pd.PaletNo';

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = CONCAT('select
    pd.PaletNo PalletNo
    ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletDetay pd
    left join paletsevk ps on pd.PaletNo=ps.SevkPaletNo  
    left Join Cins      cs on pd.mTomrukCinsiKod=cs.EskiKod
where
    pd.YeniPaletNo is Null
    and
    ps.SevkPaletNo is null 
Group By
    pd.PaletNo 
    ,cs.KaplamaIng
Order By ', @sxPaletNo);

EXEC @sql;
```

However this is rather last resort, read why here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

**Sort data in presentation layer** which is recommended behaviour and it means that you GUI component should be responsible for sorting the resultset.

Comment: but my SQL statement: Declare sxPaletNo varchar(10) set @sxPaletNo = 'pd.PaletNo' with started.

Comment: What is @sxPaletNo?

Comment: It is your variable, I skipped it at first but added it for clarity

Comment: I have a problem :

Comment: I have a problem : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 5
The identifier that starts with 'select
    pd.PaletNo PalletNo
    ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletD' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: my code: Declare sxPaletNo varchar(10)
set sxPaletNo = 'pd.PaletNo'

select
 pd.PaletNo PalletNo
 ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type
 ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletDetay pd
 left join paletsevk ps on pd.PaletNo=ps.SevkPaletNo 
 left Join Cins  cs on pd.mTomrukCinsiKod=cs.EskiKod
where
 pd.YeniPaletNo is Null
 and
 ps.SevkPaletNo is null 
Group By
 pd.PaletNo 
 ,cs.KaplamaIng
Order By sxPaletNo"  -- Not: variable character don't adding @Rafal

Comment: not sure what is the problem - could you avoid pasting whole script?

Comment: can not use special characters at variable assignments ... you will add to the code ...

Comment: Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 5
The identifier that starts with 'select
    pd.PaletNo PalletNo
    ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletD' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: I'm not sure this was your problem but there was missing @ in front of variable declaration.

Comment: it is My fault now

Comment: mine too :) I was using " instead of ' - I use too many different technologies daily....

Comment: it is My fault now:Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 5 The identifier that starts with 'select pd.PaletNo PalletNo ,isNull(cs.KaplamaIng, 'No') Type ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm from PaletD' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
The name 'select
    pd.PaletNo PalletNo
    ,cs.KaplamaIng TypeName
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Alan))) sqm
from PaletDetay pd
    left join paletsevk ps on pd.PaletNo=ps.SevkPaletNo  
    left Join Cins      cs on pd.mTomrukCinsiKod=cs.EskiKod
where
    pd.YeniPaletNo is Null
    and
    ps.SevkPaletNo is null 
Group By
    pd.PaletNo 
    ,cs.KaplamaIng
Order By pd.PaletNo' is not a valid identifier

Comment: Could you please copy and paste code again and make sure sql string is enclosed in ' (single quotes) not " (double quotes)?

Comment: It was. Thank you for your support.